# Underscore Templating and Objects within Objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Does the underscore.js template support objects within objects?

For instance, I have an object rendered such as below:

```
var person = new Person([
  {name: 'Allen', pet:[ name: 'fido', type: 'dog']},
  {name: 'Chris', pet:[ name: 'garfield', type: 'cat']}
]);
```

```html
<script type="text/template" id="template">
   <%=name%> has a pet named <%= ??? %>
</script>
```

What do I put in place of the **???** in order to get the name of the pet?

Note: I've tried `pet.name` and `pet[name]`, but both don't work. Out of ideas!

Comment: which parentheses? I assume the ones inside the object? I'm declaring an object within an object

Comment: These: `pet:([name: 'fido' type: 'dog'])` can't it be just `pet:[name: 'fido' type: 'dog']`? Also why `new Object`?

Comment: oops yes i can be :). I've made the edits

Comment: [t](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iZPr4.png)hat was a close one, but please avoid using varnames like that, `object` is [almost a reserved word](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have some syntax error there, this is the problem. You're confusing arrays with objects, and you're missing commas:

```
var data = { name: 'Allen', pet: { name: 'fido', type: 'dog' } };
var template = _.template('<%=name%> has a pet named <%=pet.name%>', data);

console.log(template); //=> Allen has a pet named fido
```

Comment: Thanks! I realized I was declaring an array of objects, and objects within objects, and it carried over to my code here.